# Hibernate ignoring @Table annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, entity

I am having an issue where the @Table(name = "tableName") is being ignored, and the class's name is being used instead.

In the example below, it is ignoring tb_users and trying to find a table called "user". Why is this happening?

Edit: So I have provided not enough information. Here is my code:

Entity

```
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username", length = 127, nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password", length = 127, nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "balance", nullable = false)
    private double balance;
}
```

Database config

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.uci.bank.repository")
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Value("${database.url}")
    String url;

    @Value("${database.user}")
    String user;

    @Value("${database.password}")
    String password;

    @Value("${database.driver}")
    String driver;

    @Value("${database.persistenceUnit}")
    String persistenceUnit;

    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    String dialect;

    @Value("${hibernate.showSql}")
    String showSql;

    @Value("${hibernate.formatSql}")
    String formatSql;

    @Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl}")
    String hbm2ddl;

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    public String getPersistenceUnit() {
        return persistenceUnit;
    }

    public String getDialect() {
        return dialect;
    }

    public String getShowSql() {
        return showSql;
    }

    public String getFormatSql() {
        return formatSql;
    }

    public String getHbm2ddl() {
        return hbm2ddl;
    }

    @Bean
    public org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {

        org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource ds = new org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName(this.driver);
        ds.setUrl(this.url);
        ds.setUsername(this.user);
        ds.setPassword(this.password);

        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

        org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(this.dataSource());
        entityManagerFactory.setPersistenceUnitName(this.persistenceUnit);
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(new org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());

        Map<String, String> jpaProperties = new HashMap<>();
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", this.dialect);
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", this.showSql);
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", this.formatSql);
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", this.hbm2ddl);
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaProperties);

        return entityManagerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager tm = new org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager();
        tm.setEntityManagerFactory(this.entityManagerFactory().getNativeEntityManagerFactory());
        return tm;
    }
}
```

Application properties

```
database.driver=org.sqlite.JDBC
database.url=jdbc:sqlite:bank.db
database.user=USERNAME
database.password=PASSWORD
database.persistenceUnit=jpaData

hibernate.dialect=com.uci.bank.dialect.SQLiteDialect
hibernate.showSql=true
hibernate.formatSql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl=validate
```

When I am trying to insert using the JpaRepository save method passing in a user, I am getting the following error message:

[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: user)

I am using SQLite and I had to create a dialect:

```
public class SQLiteIdentityColumnSupport extends IdentityColumnSupportImpl {

    @Override
    public boolean supportsIdentityColumns() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String getIdentitySelectString(String table, String column, int type) throws MappingException {
        return "select last_insert_rowid()";
    }

    @Override
    public String getIdentityColumnString(int type) throws MappingException {
        return "integer";
    }
}
```

public class SQLiteDialect extends Dialect {

```
public SQLiteDialect() {
    registerColumnType(Types.BIT, "integer");
    registerColumnType(Types.TINYINT, "tinyint");
    registerColumnType(Types.SMALLINT, "smallint");
    registerColumnType(Types.INTEGER, "integer");
    registerColumnType(Types.BIGINT, "bigint");
    registerColumnType(Types.FLOAT, "float");
    registerColumnType(Types.REAL, "real");
    registerColumnType(Types.DOUBLE, "double");
    registerColumnType(Types.NUMERIC, "numeric");
    registerColumnType(Types.DECIMAL, "decimal");
    registerColumnType(Types.CHAR, "char");
    registerColumnType(Types.VARCHAR, "varchar");
    registerColumnType(Types.LONGVARCHAR, "longvarchar");
    registerColumnType(Types.DATE, "date");
    registerColumnType(Types.TIME, "time");
    registerColumnType(Types.TIMESTAMP, "timestamp");
    registerColumnType(Types.BINARY, "blob");
    registerColumnType(Types.VARBINARY, "blob");
    registerColumnType(Types.LONGVARBINARY, "blob");
    registerColumnType(Types.BLOB, "blob");
    registerColumnType(Types.CLOB, "clob");
    registerColumnType(Types.BOOLEAN, "integer");
}

public IdentityColumnSupport getIdentityColumnSupport() {
    return new SQLiteIdentityColumnSupport();
}

public boolean hasAlterTable() {
    return false;
}

public boolean dropConstraints() {
    return false;
}

public String getDropForeignKeyString() {
    return "";
}

public String getAddForeignKeyConstraintString(String constraintName, String[] foreignKey, String referencedTable, String[] primaryKey, boolean referencesPrimaryKey) {
    return "";
}

public String getAddPrimaryKeyConstraintString(String constraintName) {
    return "";
}

public String getForUpdateString() {
    return "";
}

public String getAddColumnString() {
    return "add column";
}

public boolean supportsOuterJoinForUpdate() {
    return false;
}

public boolean supportsIfExistsBeforeTableName() {
    return true;
}

public boolean supportsCascadeDelete() {
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: what's your ORM framework? pls provide more information

Comment: Ok, updated it with more information

Comment: by the way, I am using hibernate

Answer (score 0):

try `@Entity` before `@Table` so your code will be

```
@Entity
@Table((name = "tb_users")
public class User {

...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use directly with @Entity annotation provided by hibernate

```
@Entity(name="tb_users")
public class User {

...

}
```